# AWS IoT policy doesn't restrict access

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to restrict access to my AWS IoT devices with a Policy, but my policy doesn't seem to do that. It still lets me do whatever I want to the device. The policy is practically useless. To test this, I removed the following action.

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "iot:UpdateThingShadow",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:**********:thing/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
}
```

So now my policy is this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:GetThingShadow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:**********:thing/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I try to update my thing shadow like so:

```
                    var params = {
                        thingName: "bar",
                        payload: JSON.stringify({   // payload is in string form according to docs
                            "state": {
                                "desired": {
                                    "state": 0
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    };

                    await iotdata.updateThingShadow(params, function (err, data) {
                        if (err){
                        }
                        else{
                        }
                    });
```

... it still updates my device's shadow. My policy says it can't do that though! **How can I get my policy to work?**

Answer (score 0):

In my experience,

It takes some minutes to apply completely.

I think you changed your policy and then run your test code ASAP. right?

Comment: I've waited over 24 hrs and tested again, but it still doesn't work. Is it possibly due to the fact that my IAM role has AWS IoT Full Access?

Comment: No. IAM role (IoT Full Access) is just related with access configuration of AWS. not IoT policy.